# Finding difference between total value and distinct value in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**Input Table: City**

```
  +-----------+
  |   Name    |
  +-----------+
  |   AAA     |
  +-----------+
  |   AAA     |
  +-----------+
  |   BBB     |
  +-----------+
  |   CCC     |
  +-----------+
```

The table **City** has one column `Name`. I want output that will return the difference between total numbers of city name and distinct number of city name.

In case of this table the result would be 1.

Comment: You will need to elaborate how you intend to calculate the difference. Put more data if required.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `COUNT` and `DISTINCT` `COUNT`.

```
SELECT COUNT(name)-COUNT(DISTINCT name) AS nameDifference
FROM city
```

Output:

```
nameDifference
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(Name)-COUNT(DISTINCT Name) AS NewName
FROM city
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **DISTINCT** and **COUNT**.

SELECT COUNT(name) - COUNT(DISTINCT name) FROM city

Answer (score 1):

```
select (count (*) - count(distinct value))
from city
```